# Названия вин

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Как писать названия вин: с большой или с маленькой буквы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сорта вин пишутся без кавычек и с маленькой буквы: *каберне, мускат, бастардо, рислинг*.
В то же время названия марок вин пишутся с большой буквы и в кавычках: *портвейн "Алушта", шампанское "Золотая балка".*

Answer (score 0):

как отличить сорт это или марка?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Я в тексте отвечу.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, более подробно вопрос обсуждался [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4901/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BC-%D0%BC-%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Во-вторых. Я не могу найти источник формулировки Firuze, возможно это из Розенталя, возможно из Справки на Грамоте. Но не столько важно, подобная рекомендация (присать сорта вин без кавычек и со строчной, названия марок - с заглавной и в кавычках) действительно существует, тем более аналогичные рекомендации даются и в других случаях: для автомашин, приборов и т.д.
Беда в том, что понятие сорта и марки вина действительно не так просто формализовать, не пройдя теоретический курс по специальности "сомелье". Еще более осложняется дело тем, что французская система именований вин, которую сам французы впитывают с первым глотком если не материнского молока, то молодого божоле, - эта французская система совершенно непонятна русской ментальности.
В качестве очень грубого перого приближения к "русскому" представлению могу предлодить считать сортами "родовые" названия, совпадающие с названиями сортов винограда или технологии (изабелла, херес, аи, коньяк, шампанское и т.д), а марками - конкретные названия вин подобных сортов, если они существуют. Сразу оговорюсь, что большинство таких русских названий произошли именно от **марок** французских вин, что иногда приводит к серьёзным недоразумениям.

Что же касается истинной, французской системы именования вина, то она состоит как минимум из трёхзвенной (чаще - четырёх и пяти) системы, включающей в общем случае название сорта - в нашем понимании - винограда, типа купажа, если есть, винодельческого региона (самое важное), технологии, марки фирмы-производителя, иногда - качества и сахаристости. 
Понятно, что эта информация вряд ли может быть доступна простому русскому "филологу", размышляющуму на написанием накладной на поставку двадцати ящиков "Плодово-выгодного". Иногда выручают словари. Но учтите, что и в них встречаются многочисленные расхождения по отнесению конрктного названия к сорту или марке.