# Как писать Бастардо м(М)агарачский?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Как писать такой сорт винограда, как Бастардо м(М)агарачский? "Каберне-Совиньон" вроде бы два слова с прописной, должна сработать аналогия по идее. Или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего написание в общем случае пока не нормировано.
Я в курсе, т.к. на gramota.ru года четыре назад изрядно копий сломали, в чем и мне довелось участвовать. Попозже попробую найти ту ветку.
Тут вот какая штука. Строго говоря, в типичном случае приведенные вами названия не являются названиями сортов винограда. Они используются только как обозначение происхождения сырья при производстве вина. Первая часть такого названия в типичном случае представляет собой собственно сорт, вторая обычно - место производства, винодельческий регион, реже - региональный тип купажа (что для хороших вин вообще редкость).
На такие названия нет закреплённой орфографической кодификации, приходится руководствоваться общими принципами.

Исходя из них предлжил бы:
**Каберне Совиньон** (как родовое и видовое обозначение ср. Хомо Сапиенс); здесь не следует путать уточняющее Совиньон с самостоятельными сортами Совиньон Блан, Совиньон Руж и др., к этим сортам Каберне Совиньон отношения не имеет.

**Бастардо магарачский** - поскольку название связано с названием института "Магарач", создавшим этот "сорт", магарачский здесь обычное прилагательное.

Но, повторюсь, это личное мнение.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень полезная информация! Вопрос возник как раз потому, что в этикетках вин нужно унифицировать написание. И мне подсказали, что в техинструкции закреплено именно "Бастардо магарачский", что вполне логично, как я теперь понимаю. Хотя иногда написание в такого рода документах не соответствует литературной норме.

Answer (score 0):

Внесу уточнение. Сравнивать Каберне Совиньон с Homo sapiens не совсем правильно. В латинских названиях живых существ с прописной буквы пишется только название рода, вид же - со строчной: Canis domestica, Ehium vulgare и т.д.

Comment: Здесь не стоит подходить с позиций правильно-неправильно. Уместно ли сравнение - вот как можно было бы ставить вопрос.  
Всякое сравнение справедливо в рамках некоего поля рассмотрения. Я не имел в виду этим српавнением обосновывать или опроверкать написание с заглавной, оно и так очевидно. Речь шла о том, что там нет причин для дефиса. 
А сравнением пояснял, что Совиньон здесь не равноправная составляющая, а лишь "видовое" название при "родовом" Каберне.

Comment: Ок, значит, пока пишем "Каберне Совиньон" и "Бастардо магарачский". Спасибо!